# Using moment, How to get date and hours as format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am working on a project that requires this kind of text response on a day and hours.

"1d 23hrs"-- data as milliseconds, also I am using moment js. i tried so many times but cannot cath the format days i got only -- 1 23--- without "d hrs".

can anyone help me to do this ?
here is the function which i have tried

```
const milliSec = 85600000;
const days = moment(moment.duration(milliSec)._data).format('D HH');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add text to your date format by adding a set of `[]` around the text you want to add like this.

```
days2 = moment(moment.duration(milliSec)._data).format('D[d] HH[h]');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Really appreciate.  And if our answer is 1h 30mins, how to roundup to 2hrs ?

Answer (score 0):

To escape characters in format strings, you can wrap the characters in square brackets.

In your case to add custom text try this:

```js
const milliSec = 85600000;
const days = moment(moment.duration(milliSec)._data).format("D[d] HH[hrs]");
console.log(days);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @vjr12 . Really appreciate. And if our answer is 1h 30mins, how to roundup to 2hrs ?